# swap 2 node in doubly linked list without swapping the data C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Im trying to swap position of two node in doubly linked list without swapping the data, this is my code, it came up with wrong answer when run through this testcase:

the list length:
20

the list:
2158 2398 300 2268 3655 765 3792 4038 1761 4762 1292 3200 3882 962 488 1938 3757 3122 302 640

positions to swap:
9 12

the right answer is:         2158 2398 300 2268 3655 765 3792 4038 3200 ***1292 4762*** 1761 3882 962 488 1938 3757 3122 302 640

but mine got a bit different:2158 2398 300 2268 3655 765 3792 4038 3200 ***4762 1292*** 1761 3882 962 488 1938 3757 3122 302 640.
I need some help here

```
/*struct ListNode {
        int val;
        ListNode *left;
        ListNode *right;
        ListNode(int x = 0, ListNode *l = nullptr, ListNode* r = nullptr) : val(x), left(l), right(r) {}
    };
    */
    
    ListNode* reverse(ListNode* head, int a, int b) {
        //To Do
        if(a==b) return head;
        ListNode* h = head;
        ListNode* anode = new ListNode;
        ListNode* bnode = new ListNode;
        int n(1);
        for(int i(1); h!= nullptr; i++){
            if(i == a){
                anode = h;
                
            }
            if(i == b){
                bnode = h;
                // break; // now h = bnode
            }
            ++n;
            h= h->right;
        }
        ListNode* bleft = new ListNode;
        ListNode* bright = new ListNode;
        bright = bnode->right;
        bleft = bnode->left;
        
        bnode->right = anode->right;
        bnode->right->left = bnode;
        if(a==1){
            
        }
        else{
            bnode->left = anode->left;
            bnode->left->right = bnode;
        }
        
        anode->left = bleft;
        bleft->right = anode;
        if(bright ==nullptr){
            anode->right = nullptr;
            
        }
        else{
            anode->right = bright;
            bright->left = anode;
        }
        if(a==1) return bnode;
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: Reversing a double-linked list is kind of useless, as you can easily iterate over it from either direction. Going forward or reverse is just a matter of where you start and which pointer you follow.

Comment: As for swapping two nodes (which isn't really needed if you want to actually reverse the list) have you tried doing it using pencil and paper first? Draw a list on paper, using squares for the nodes, and arrows for the pointers and links. Then erase and redraw arrows to attempt your swap. Don't code it until you think you have it working on paper. And create a separate function to do the swapping, which makes it easier to test and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer, as well as the name of the function you are supposed to write, suggest that you should reverse a sublist. Your code doesn't attempt to do that. It swaps positions of the first and the last nodes of the sublist. These are two different operations. The reverse operation generally needs a loop to iterate over the nodes of the sublist.

On an unrelated note, you code has four totally useless `new` expressions. They contribute nothing but memory leaks. Just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If you did need to swap two nodes, to handle non-adjacent and adjacent nodes with the same code, swap what is pointing to the two nodes first, then swap the two nodes next and previous pointers.

```
void SwapNodes(NODE **phead, NODE **ptail, NODE *a, NODE *b)
{
NODE **apn;   /* a->prev->next */
NODE **anp;   /* a->next->prev */
NODE **bpn;   /* b->prev->next */
NODE **bnp;   /* b->next->prev */
NODE *ptmp;
    if(*phead == a)
        apn = phead;
    else
        apn = &a->prev->next;
    if(*phead == b)
        bpn = phead;
    else
        bpn = &b->prev->next;
    if(*ptail == a)
        anp = ptail;
    else
        anp = &a->next->prev;
    if(*ptail == b)
        bnp = ptail;
    else
        bnp = &b->next->prev;
    *apn = b;
    *bpn = a;
    *anp = b;
    *bnp = a;
    ptmp = a->prev;
    a->prev = b->prev;
    b->prev = ptmp;
    ptmp = a->next;
    a->next = b->next;
    b->next = ptmp;
}
```

If the list is a circular list that includes a dummy node where dummy.next points to first node and dummy.prev points to last node, then all of the checks for head and tail are not needed, and only the two pointer to node parameters are needed.